# Encoding within SQL statement

Tags: php, sql

Hi i'm having difficulty passing in a value containing an `ó` into a SQL statement.

The while loop will not run due to the statement not running. The statement runs fine with any other values passed in except this particular one.

Is there a way I can encode the statement so that it runs?

I cannot change the `ó` for a normal `o` as the value in the database contains an `ó`.

The code I have been trying is below.

Cheers

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$choicetest = 'óvil';



$query = "SELECT test FROM [testtable] WHERE test = '$choicetest' GROUP BY test"; 
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
while ($line = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {


  $var = 'hello'; 

}

?>
```

Comment: Or use another collation when doing the comparison, one treating ó as o.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the table's default character set is UTF8. Then, before any queries, issue these:

`SET NAMES utf8; SET CHARCTER SET utf8`

Then your query should work as expected.

Comment: Hi, is there a method around this if the database is in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ? as i cannot change the collation due to read only access? cheers